# MySQL recursive selection from one table

Tags: mysql, recursion

I have this table in `MySQL`:

```
| id | mainid | name                |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | 0      | main 1              |
| 2  | 1      | sub 1               |
| 3  | 1      | sub 2               |
| 4  | 1      | sub 3               |
| 5  | 4      | subsub 1            |
| 6  | 4      | subsub 2            |
| 7  | 0      | main 2              |
| 8  | 7      | sub 4               |
| 9  | 7      | sub 5               |
```

The `mainid` field is associate with `id` field.

Is there a best practice in MySQL commands to select all row recursive? I want to `select` all subitems under main item.

I tried to select all subitems on first level for example sub 1, sub 2, sub3 is under main 1. This is simple:

```
SELECT id, mainid, name FROM mytable WHERE mainid = '1';
```

But is there a one-line-command to select same rows AND the subsub1 and subsub 2 rows too? (And of cours if I create another deeper levels thats too.)

Comment: Choices include, but are not limited to, the following: - Join the table to itself as many times as could possibly be required - Handle the recursion at the application level, e.g. with a PHP loop - Use a Stored Procedure to handle the recursion
- Switch to a Nested Set (or some sort of hybrid model) instead of the 'so-called' Adjacency List model All of these solutions are discussed more thoroughly elsewhere, including a number of excellent, popular, and hence easily googled, articles on Hierarchical data and MySQL.

Comment: [Trees in SQL](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html) might also be of help

Answer (score 0):

you'll need temp tables and separate stored procedures

first stored procedure will receive the "parent" id and create a result temp table:

RESULT (id, mainid, name)

and a check temp table

CHECK (id, passed)
(this table is necessary to avoid infinite loops)

So, the idea is that you call the inner stored procedure, and the inner stored is something like this

PROC (currentId (int))

with the parent id and the proc will do basically what your query did, but save it in a inner temp table, and then for each element of that temp table (that is not in CHECK) it will mark it as passed in CHECK (just insert the row) and call the same proc for each of the "children" of currentId

Then insert all data from the inner temp table into RESULT and you'll have your entire list of descendants

you have 2 ways

check children and then insert into RESULT
or
insert into RESULT and then check children

the data will be ordered differently but the result should be the same